# MYSQL: Replacing FQDN with hostname only

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join, crud

I have mysql table with three fields

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
server2           11.1.1.1      2011-12-18 21:56:46
server2.abc.com   11.1.1.1      2011-12-17 21:56:46

Here,
host --> varchar
ipaddress --> varchar
date ---> datetime
```

I want to replace all FQDN values with hostname only.
My output should look as below:

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
server2           11.1.1.1      2011-12-18 21:56:46
server2           11.1.1.1      2011-12-17 21:56:46
```

I have written the following:

```
UPDATE table1 SET host = TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM host)
```

Comment: do you use a mysql/mariadb version that supports "REGEXP_REAPLACE" ? if so, you can simply use this function (`REGEXP_REPLACE(host, '\\..+', '')`

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `REGEXP_REPLACE` (if your MySQL/MariaDB supports this function) or (classical) `SUBSTRING` in combination with `LOCATE`:

1. `UPDATE table1 SET host = SUBSTRING(host, 1, LOCATE('.', host)-1)`
2. `UPDATE table1 SET host = REGEXP_REPLACE(host, '\\..+', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the first occurrence of dot then do a left function to truncate the string.

```
update yourTable 
   set host = left(host,locate('.',host)-1);
```